# Cannot perform boxing using as keyword for a string reference type in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Boxing Conversion can be acheived by using as keyword
So I tried to perform boxing using `as` keyword.

So I tried the below example
Eg 1:-

```
 int i = 12;
 string a = i.ToString(); // Boxing Conversion
 Console.WriteLine(a); //This works
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Eg 2:-

```
var aa = i as object; // This works
var a = (i as string) // Compile time error
var a = (i as string).ToString(); // Compile time error
```

Can anyone explain why boxing can't be performed using `as` keyword for a string reference type?

Comment: The C# compiler can tell that converting `int` to `string` can never work so slams the emergency stop button early.  You can do this sort of thing in VB.NET, not C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
int i = 12;
string a = i.ToString();
```

ToString() is not a boxing conversion at all (and I'm not sure the term is quite right - boxing is just boxing). It is conversion to string. "a" is totally different object, not related to i anymore. It's type is string and value is "12", not 12.

2)

```
int i = 12;
var aa = i as object;
```

It is boxing, but aa still keeps object of int type.

```
var a = (i as string)
```

Here you are trying to convert int to string, which is impossible to do what way.

What you are trying to do here is usual in many languages, like JavaScript. But C# has very strong rules about type conversions. And most of the time, you cannot just cast type to string and back.